# Crazy exception after replacing my app EXE

Tags: c#, wpf

For testing reasons I always replaced my (testing machine) exe after making changes to it (in my development machine). This seemed to work fine up until recently, when suddenly whenever I try to do this I get this error. I don't get it immediately - my app has tab control, and the error doesn't appear on all tabs, only on some of them (specific tabs, reproduced all the time).

Strange enough - this does not happen with the installed EXE. It also runs perfectly on my development machine in debug mode (so remote debugging didn't help).  Only when I try to replace the installer exe with my newly compiled exe - I get this error. And only when I click on one of those specific tabs.

```
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveAssembly(BamlAssembly)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetAssembly(Int16)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.EnsureXmlnsAssembliesLoaded(System.String)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(System.String, System.String, System.Xaml.XamlType[])
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.XamlContext.GetXamlType(System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeName, Boolean, Boolean)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.XamlContext.ResolveXamlType(System.String, Boolean)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext.ServiceProvider_Resolve(System.String)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePropertyName(System.String, System.Object, System.Type, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePathParts(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPath..ctor(System.String, System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathConverter.ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension, System.IServiceProvider)

> Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Windows.DependencyObject>, System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Hashtable>)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Windows.DependencyObject>)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory, Int32, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32, System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement, System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement, System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Input.IKeyboardInputProvider, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.DependencyObject, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.SetFocus()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at ProjectName.App.Main()
```

Comment: How does the code look, that produces that error? How should anyone give you an answer without knowing what you are doing? :)

Comment: It looks like, your missing some Xaml-Files.

Comment: @TobiasTheel Thanks, you are right of-course, but since I can't pinpoint the problem, I will spare you from reading +20,000 lines of code.

Comment: @Nikolaus I tried copying the app.config (renaming it to my AppName.Exe.Config) - still no go

Comment: try install the full .net instead of client profile on the machine having this problem. If its the case then you might need to mark certain references as copy to directory

Comment: This is very strange. I tried copying files 1 by 1 from the development build to the installation folder in test-computer. Every time it failed. On the last file it succeeded. I thought maybe it was that file. But when I tried again and only copied that dll - no go. Argh...

Answer (score 3):

```
How can I figure out what this problem is and fix it.
```

Perform a remote debug using the [visual studio remote debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=475).

[This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) gives an idea of how to use it.

Once you get familiar with the VS Remote Debug, you will always use this powerful tool to test on a potential client environment.

Hope I could help

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!

Comment: Good luck on your problem

Comment: Well, it was nice setting it up, but it doesn't help. The problem does not reproduce on my development machine (when I run it inside VisualStudio with debugger), and it didn't reproduce on remote debugging either. The problem only occurs if I replace the installation EXE with the EXE from my development machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the reason. In my project I had an extra dll reference that was not really used in the code (RibbonControlsLibrary.dll), but it was not added to the build of the Installer. This is what caused the error. When I replaced the exe, the development exe looked for this file and couldn't find it.

It was solved by removing this dll from the project references.